# Angular Grid doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-grid

In public folder in laravel project is stored ag-grid folder. Here's content of default.blade.php where are stored all links to css and js scripts.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script scr="http://demos.angularcode.com/grid/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/1.0.0/dist/ng-table.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/ag-grid/dist/angular-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/ag-grid/dist/theme-blue.css" />
<script src="/js/ag-grid/dist/angular-grid.js"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/dashboard/novi.controller.js') }}"></script>
```

Here's my controller

```
var kongres = angular.module('kongres', ["angularGrid"]);
kongres.controller('NoviController', NoviController);
function NoviController($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.title = 'nsdlob';

var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Broj fakture", field: "broj_zavodjenja", width: 110, sort: 'desc'},
    {
        headerName: "Datum zavodjenja",
        field: "rm_izlaz_master_datum_zavodjenja",
        width: 130,
        cellClass: 'grid-align'
    },
    {headerName: "Datum valute", field: "rm_izlaz_master_datum_valute", width: 130, cellClass: 'grid-align'},
    {headerName: "Vrsta dokmenta", field: "naziv", width: 240},
    {headerName: "Partner", field: "partneri_naziv", width: 300},
    {headerName: "Napomena", field: "napomena", width: 300},
    {headerName: "Broj artikala", field: "brart", width: 105, cellClass: 'grid-align'},
    {headerName: "Ukupno", field: "ukupno", width: 150, cellClass: 'grid-align-right'}
];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    enableColResize: true,
    groupHeaders: true,
    rowHeight: 32,
    showToolPanel: true,
    rowGroupPanelShow: 'always',
    enableStatusBar: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    rowSelection: 'single',
    onRowClicked: function (event) {
        $state.go('faktura-detail', {id: event.data.id});
    },
    enableFilter: true
};
}
```

Here's my page where grid should be displayed

```
@extends(isset($layout)?$layout:'layout.default')
@section('content')

<div class="page-content-wrapper" ng-controller="NoviController">
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT BODY -->
    <div class="page-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 portlet light bordered">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption font-dark">
                        <i class="icon-people"></i>
                        <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">Hotel bookings</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    @{{ title }}
                    <div ag-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 600px;" class="ag-blue"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

@stop
But when I open this page, grid is showed without any posibility to group, drag order, etc. It looks like ap-grid.js is not included.

Comment: have you tried to include it like: `<script src="{{ URL::asset('path/to/angular-grid.js') }}"></script>` ?

Comment: It's my mistake. After storing data in grid, everything works as expected.